# How can validate only a certain fields in php Laravel 5?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently working on my Edit form in my Laravel application.

I request all the inputs from a form submit. I got :

```
array:6 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "iWyonRYFjF15wK8fVXJiTkX09YSPmXukyGbBcHRA"
  "phone" => "9786770863"
  "email" => "test@sites.com1"
  "address" => "23 School St Lowell MA 01851"
  "$id" => "1"
]
```

My goal is to only validate only : phone, email, and address.

I've tried

```
$validator = Validator::make(

            ['phone' => 'max:20'],
            ['email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $id ],
            ['address' => 'max:255']

        );

    // dd(Input::get('email')); // HERE <------ I got the email to display 

    if ( $validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to('user/profile/'. $id )->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    } else {



        $user          = User::findOrFail($id);
        $user->phone   = Input::get('phone');
        $user->email   = Input::get('email');
        $user->address = Input::get('address');

        $user->save();
```

It keep failing on me and say that

`The email field is required.`

But if I recall correctly the email field is there.

**How can validate only a certain fields in php Laravel 5 ?**

Comment: I got the email to display `"test@sites.com1"`

Comment: I think the concatenation of the id could be the issue. Why do you do this?

Comment: Same error. This is very wired. When I take off `required` , it works. But that will be disaster.

Comment: I did that concatenation because I want to ignore the unique of email while editing.

Comment: You call the function the wrong way. First is the data you want to check against, second the rules.

Comment: You should accept an answer in case someone runs into the same issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be :

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'phone' => 'max:20',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $id ,
            'address' => 'max:255']
        );
```

It thinks you are passing the first line as the data to check, and the second line as the rules for your validation. It doesn't find an email key so it tells you it is required.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Validator::make()` method call is a bit off.

When using this function, the first parameter is the array of data to validate (your request data), and the second parameter is your array of rules.

Your current code has you passing in three parameters. It is treating `['phone' => 'max:20']` as your data to validate, `['email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $id ],` as your rule, and then `['address' => 'max:255']` as your messages array.

It should be something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    [
        'phone' => 'max:20',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'. $id,
        'address' => 'max:255'
    ]
);
```